# Using Subquery in Sequence function PrestoSQL

Tags: sql, sequence, presto, subquery, trino

Use case - 
I am trying to find weekly frequency of a customer from a dataset. Now, not all customers have "events" happening in all of the weeks, and I would need to fill them in with zero values for the "count" column.

I was trying to do this using the sequence function of PrestoSQL. However, this would need me to get the value of max week from the customer's orders itself ( I don't want to hardcode this since the result would be going into a BI tool and I dont want to update this manually every week )

```
with all_orders_2020  as (select customer, cast(date_parse(orderdate, '%Y-%m-%d') as date) as order_date 
from orders 
where orderdate > '2020-01-01' and customer in (select customer from some_customers)),

orders_with_week_number as (select *, week(order_date) as week_number from all_orders_2020),

weekly_count as (select customer, week_number, count(*) as ride_count from orders_with_week_number
where customer = {{some_customer}} group by customer, week_number)

SELECT
    week_number
FROM
    (VALUES
        (SEQUENCE(1,(select max(week_number) from weekly_count)))
    ) AS t1(week_array)
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(week_array) AS t2(week_number)
```

Presto complaints about this saying -

```
Unexpected subquery expression in logical plan: (SELECT "max"(week_number)
FROM
  weekly_count
)
```

Any clues how this can be done ?

Comment: Instead of `VALUES sequence(subquery)`, try `subquery CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequence(...)) ... `. Also join the `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html) for more interactive troubleshooting.

Comment: Subqueries in VALUES are not yet supported. If you care about this case please file an issue about it here: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar use case and followed the example from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html

Bring the SEQUENCE out and define the subquery using a WITH clause:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT SEQUENCE(1, (SELECT MAX(week_number) FROM weekly_count)) AS week_array
)
SELECT week_number FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(week_array) as t(week_number)
```